# Is $\{f \in End_{\mathbb R}(\mathbb R^n) : d(f(x),f(y))=(x,y) \space \forall x,y \in \mathbb R^n\}$ a group?

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to figure out if the set $\{f  \in End_{\mathbb R}(\mathbb R^n) : d(f(x),f(y))=(x,y) \space \forall x,y \in \mathbb R^n\}$ is a group under the operation composition ($d$ is a metric).

Clearly the identity is in the set, and I've also checked that the set is closed under the operation; since the composition is associative, the only thing that remains to check is that inverses also belong to $A$. I have the feeling that this is not always the case, I suppose it depends on the metric $d$, but I can't think of a counterexample. I would appreciate some ideas.

Comment: Since $d(f(x),f(y))=d(x,y)$, f is automatically injective by the $0\leq d(x,y)$. f being endomorphism implies that f is surjective. So f has an inverse under this property. The inverse exists and composition works. So it is a group.

Comment: In finite-dimensional, there is equivalent between : (1) injective , (2) surjective and (3) bijective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $f^{-1}$ exists, from $d(fx,fy)=d(x,y)$ we get $$d(f^{-1}x',f^{-1}y')=d(ff^{-1}x',ff^{-1}y')=d(x',y')$$